# Creating a generic XSLT document to transform any non-root Element with child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The following question targets a sample XML file that looks like this

```
<root>
   <Name>Name1</Name>
   <Description>Description1</Description>
   <Application>
      <ApplicationItem>1</ApplicationItem>
      <ApplicationItem>2</ApplicationItem>
      <ApplicationItem>3</ApplicationItem>
   </Application>
   <Location>
      <LocationItem>1</LocationItem>
      <LocationItem>2</LocationItem>
   </Location>
</root>
```

My goal is to have any non-root element with child elements (known to be named identically to its parent with a suffix of 'Item', and transforming it so that the child elements are removed and replaced with a delimited string for the parent value.  I was able to do it by targeting the parent and child elements specifically with the following.

```
  <!-- Copy over entire XML document -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Find Application and apply ApplicationItem template to it-->
  <xsl:template match="Application">
    <Application>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ApplicationItem" />
    </Application>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Transform and remove ApplicationItem -->
  <xsl:template match="ApplicationItem">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(., substring('|', 1 div not(position()=last())))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Find Location and apply LocationItem template to it-->
  <xsl:template match="Location">
    <Location>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LocationItem" />
    </Location>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Transform and remove LocationItem -->
  <xsl:template match="LocationItem">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(., substring('|', 1 div not(position()=last())))"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

However I would like to be able to create a generic xslt without having to specify any of the elements specifically, but to apply the above transformation to **any non-root element with children.**  A pseudocode example below

```
  <!-- Copy over entire XML document -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- Find non-root parent and apply child template to it-->
  <xsl:template match="*parent with children*">
    <*ParentElementName*>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*ChildElementName OR ParentElementName+Item*" />
    </*ParentElementName*>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Transform and remove *ChildElementName* -->
  <xsl:template match="*ChildElementName*">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(., substring('|', 1 div not(position()=last())))"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Can I apply a generic template that would apply to any element that fits the above criteria?  My actual xml file has dozens of the above nexted xml examples and that feed may be getting additional instances in the future, I would like to have an xslt transform all of them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To realize it, use the *identity template* in combination with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = concat(local-name(..),'Item')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[local-name() = local-name(current())]) > 0">|</xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>
```

To get rid of spurious spaces, you can also add the template

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space(.))]" />
```

or add this element at the root level

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Then the test output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <Description>Description1</Description>
  <Application>1|2|3</Application>
  <Location>1|2</Location>
</root>
```